# Fastreport and vertical align with Delphi

Tags: delphi, report, fastreport

I have create a report with Fastreport. In this report I have (from top to botton of page) some strings, a sub report and then other some strings:

Report structure
--Top lines--
--Subreport--
--Bottom lines--

My problem is: when the sub report have many lines some of this lines go over the the "main" strings of report.

I'd like avoid it. So I'd like move "bottom objects" of report after subreport text (if necessary on new page).

[image]

Is it possible?

This is the report: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cvnmzx0tklh7697/invoice.fr3?dl=0

Comment: I don't know Fastreport, but in QuickReport you would create a separate band for that. What component is `SubreportDeposits` ?

Comment: I can't see any bands in your design, you would have a masterband and place the subreport in a childband below with option stretch, bottom lines should be placed in a footerband for the master band.

Comment: @bummi can I ask you to help about band. I'm not a expert of FastReport :) This is the report link https://www.dropbox.com/s/cvnmzx0tklh7697/invoice.fr3?dl=0 I don't use any database I pass all value by code.

Comment: This would get to broad for here. Anything which is night grow (Subreports/Memos/Images) will overlap the following elements. The only clean way to avoid this is using bands, every kind of band has his own purpose and behavior. Googeling "fastreports bands" will lead to helpfiles and many examples. take a look on Stretchmode of the components and streched of the bands. Bands can be used without databinding too, just omit dataset and set recordcount to 1.